# Xamarin Android Map stop working

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Forms Portable application with Android and iOS. My maps have been working fine and still are in the iOS, but in Android I just get a map of the whole world.
This is the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<application android:label="MyProject" android:icon="@drawable/appicon">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaS...................................." />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

This is my Page for booth Android and iOS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Comca.Views;assembly=Comca"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Comca.Controls;assembly=Comca"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Comca;assembly=Comca"
        xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
        x:Class="Comca.Pages.LocationsPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <views:PageHeader></views:PageHeader>
            <controls:CustomMap x:Name="myMap" MapType="Street"
                WidthRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenWidth}"
                HeightRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenHeight}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The myMap.MoveToRegion does nothing. It goes true setting all the pins but nothing happens, still a map of the whole world.

```
namespace MyProject.Pages
{
    public partial class LocationsPage : ContentPage
    {
        LocationsViewModel LocationsVM { get; set; }
        public List<LocationsResponse> Locations { get; set;}
        public LocationsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myMap.MoveToRegion(
                            MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                                new Position(26.142051, -81.794683), Distance.FromMiles(4)));
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            if (this.BindingContext != null)
            {
                LocationsVM = this.BindingContext as LocationsViewModel;
                if (LocationsVM.Locations != null)
                {
                    Locations = LocationsVM.Locations;
                    foreach (var location in Locations)
                    {
                        var latitude = Convert.ToDouble(location.Latitude);
                        var longitude = Convert.ToDouble(location.Longitude);                       
                        var label = $"{location.Name} - {location.Plaza}";
                        var address = $"{location.Street} {location.Citystate}";
                        var pin = new CustomPin
                        {
                            Pin = new Pin
                            {
                                Type = PinType.Place,
                                Position = new Position(latitude, longitude),
                                Label = label,
                                Address = address
                            },
                            Hours = location.Hours,
                            Phone = location.Phone,
                            Id="Myname",
                            Url = "http://www.myname.com"
                        };

                        myMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
                        myMap.Pins.Add(pin.Pin);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that on the customMapRenderer the if (e.PropertyName.Equals("VisibleRegion") && !isDrawn)  never equals VisibleRegion.
First it's Renderer, then Y, then Width and last Height.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using CustomRenderer.Droid;
using MyProject.Controls;
using MyProject.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
using MyProject.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        GoogleMap map;
        List<CustomPin> customPins;
        bool isDrawn;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            map.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        map = googleMap;
        map.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
        map.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("VisibleRegion") && !isDrawn)  
        {
            map.Clear();

            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                var marker = new MarkerOptions();
                marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Pin.Position.Longitude));
                marker.SetTitle(pin.Pin.Label);
                marker.SetSnippet(pin.Pin.Address);

                map.AddMarker(marker);
            }
            isDrawn = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        if (changed)
        {
            isDrawn = false;
        }
    }

    void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Phone))
        {

            var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + customPin.Phone);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, url);
            //intent.SetData(url);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
        if (inflater != null)
        {
            Android.Views.View view;

            var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);

            var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
            var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);
            var infoHours = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowHours);
            var infoPhone = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowsPhone);

            if (infoTitle != null)
            {
                infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
            }
            if (infoSubtitle != null)
            {
                infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
            }
            if (infoHours != null)
            {
                infoHours.Text = customPin.Hours;
            }
            if (infoPhone != null)
            {
                infoPhone.Text = customPin.Phone;
            }

            return view;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }

    CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I took over this code and I'm new to Xamarin.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: In your `AndroidManifest`, are you put the `<meta-data .../>` like [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/#Adding_the_Key_to_Your_Project) ?

Comment: Yes, I just edit the above too reflect it.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo or share a more complete code?

Comment: That is the complete code.